# How can I get a street from a zipcode using google API

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I want to use google API to get the street address from a zip code so that when a user fills out his zip code in my registration form I then can automatically fill the street of the user.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, because there can be multiple street addresses for any ZIP code.

For example, look up "Beverly Hills, CA 90210" in Google Maps. You can see there are streets such as "Lomitas Avenue" and "Sunset Boulevard" for this ZIP code.